# Calling a class from an imported module

Tags: python

Probably stupid question, and I've read many of the similar threads on here but still can't fathom the answer:

in main.py

```
from userMod import *

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self): #some code here etc
```

in userMod.py

```
class signup(Handler):
    def get(self): #some code here etc
```

I get an error saying that Handler is not defined. My simple yet clearly stupid question is how can I access classes from a parent script within a loaded module? Or is it that I simply need to duplicate Handler in each module I create?

Bear in mind I've very new to Python and trying to make my code more modular by splitting out certain types of functions (in this case the user login and registration component of the site I'm building).

Comment: That's not how importing works. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Thanks to RocketDonkey and Sebastian Kreft below for the solution:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In usermod.py you need to import main, not the other way around.

Comment: Please forgive my complete ignorance... I have a main.py which contains the bulk of my code and is called from app.yaml as the landing point for the site. I want to move all of my user functions (login, registration, etc) into a separate module to save on the amount of code in main.py... so I move them into userMod.py and import that into main. I don't see or understand how I can import main into userMod unless I simply add import main to the top of userMod, however then I am importing both into both... ??? Surely I'm getting this wrong? Is there a better way to structure script architecture?

Comment: In your case just move then the Handler class to userMod. In case the Handler class is used in some other modules as well, you will need to have another module and call it maybe common.py or utils.py and import  that one in all modules requiring the Handler class.

Comment: Thanks... this is a much better solution. Handler is going to be used as the base class for all of these so it would make sense to put it into it's own and import it into everything.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for certain without seeing your code, but in that very basic snippet you basically have the imports reversed. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams provided a link that will describe the whole process in general (and definitely better than I can), but at a basic level, each module exists in its own namespace and isn't aware of other modules unless you tell it about them.

So in your case, when you subclass `Handler`, the module has no idea what `Handler` is because it 1.) isn't a built-in, and 2.) hasn't been imported. Try this in `usermod.py`:

```
import main

class signup(main.Handler):
    def get(self): #some code here etc
```

and see if it does what you want.

Comment: ah ok... before posting on SO I had already read the article linked by Ignacio, however I still thought that an imported Module might be able to access the parents classes somehow, clearly not. in my case main.py contains the vast bulk of my code and it seems odd to import it back into this much smaller module simply to gain access to the Handler class. If there is no other way to do it then I will simply duplicate the Handler class in each module that requires it. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: You could do something like `from main import Handler` to pull only that class. Or just bundle all the Handlers in one place.